# Azure SQL DB Error, This location is not available for subscription

Tags: azure-sql-server

I am having pay as you go subscription and I am creating an Azure SQL server.

While adding server, on selection of location, I am getting this error:

```
This location is not available for subscriptions
```

Please help.

Comment: which location did you choose for the Azure SQL server?

Comment: This issue is coming with all available locations.

Comment: Suggest you call the Azure Support to get helps.

Comment: [The full explanation and optional solution is here](http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/247/).
In short, This is The Azure Coronavirus (COVID-19) effect 
The demand grows dramatically and unprecedented, challenging service providers like Microsoft all around the world. This issue is manly effect free subscriptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can reference this blog: [Azure / SQL Server / This location is not available for subscription](https://blog.sqlserveronline.com/2018/10/22/azure-sql-server-this-location-is-not-available-for-subscription/). It has the same error with you.

Run this powershell command to check if the location you choose is available:

```
Get-AzureRmLocation | select displayname
```

If the location is available, the best way to resolve this issue just contact the Azure support to have this enabled for you. You can do this for free using support page on your Azure Portal.
[image]

[image]

[image]

They well contact you can help you solve it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

There's an actual issue with Microsoft servers. They have too many Azure SQL database creation requests. They're currently trying to handle the situation. This seems to affect all types of subscriptions even paid ones. I have a Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription and I get the same error (This location is not available for subscriptions) for all locations.

See following Microsoft forum thread for more information:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac0376cb-2a0e-4dc2-a52c-d986989e6801/ongoing-issue-unable-to-create-sql-database-server?forum=ssdsgetstarted

Answer (score 8):

As the other answer states, this is a (poorly handled) restriction on Azure as of now and there seems to be no ETA on when it shall be lifted

In the meantime, you can still get an SQL database up and running in Azure, if you don't mind doing a bit of extra work and don't want to wait - just set up a Docker instance and put MSSQL on it!

- In the Azure Portal, create a container instance. Use the following docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/
- while creating, you might have to set the ACCEPT_EULA environment variable to "Y".
- after it boots up (10-20 minutes for me), in the portal, connect to it with the "sqlcmd" command and set up your login. In my case, I just needed a quick demo db, so I took the "sa" login, ran "alter login SA with password ='{insert your password}'" and "alter login SA enable". See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples

and voila, you have an SQL instance on Azure. Although it's unmanaged and poorly monitored, it might be enough for a short-term solution. The IP address of the docker instance can be found in the Properties section of the container instance blade.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved myself. Let me tell you the problem first. Then the solution.

Problem: I created a brand new free Azure account (comes with $250 free credit) for a client. Then upgraded to pay-as-you-go subscription. I was unable to create Azure SQL db. The error was 'location is not available'.

How I solved: I created another pay-as-you-go subscription in the same account. Guess what - I was able to create SQL db in my new subscription right away. Then I deleted the first subscription from my account. And yes, I lost the free credit.

If your situation is similar to mine, you can try this.

PS: I have 3 clients with their own Azure accounts. I was able to create SQL Db in all of their accounts. I think the problem arises only for free accounts and/or for free accounts that upgraded to pay-as-you-go accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, it is really irritating about the poor prompt string of Azure...

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT - 2020/04/22

This is still an ongoing problem up to today, but I was told by Microsoft support that on April 24th, a new Azure cluster will be available in Europe. Thus it might get possible to finally deploy SQL Server instances on Free accounts around there.

---

## Deploy a docker container running SQL Server

To complement on @Filip's answer, and given that the problem still remains with Azure SQL Server, a docker container running a SQL Server is a great alternative. You can set yourself one very easily running the following command on the cloud shell:

```
az container create --image microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express --os-type Windows --name <ContainerName> --resource-group <ResourceGroupName> --cpu <NumberOfCPUs> --memory <Memory> --port 1433 --ip-address public --environment-variables ACCEPT_EULA=Y SA_PASSWORD=<Password> MSSQL_PID=Developer --location <SomeLocationNearYou>
```

<**ContainerName**> : A container name of your choice

<**ResourceGroupName**> : The name of a previously created Resource Group

<**NumberOfCPUs**> : Number of CPUs you want to use

<**Memory**> : Memory you want to use

<**Password**> : Your password

<**SomeLocationNearYou**> : A location near you. For example,
*westeurope*

---

## Access SQL Server

Once the container instance is deployed, in the Overview you will be able to find an IP address. Use that IP address and the password you chose in the `az container` command to connect to the SQL Server, either using Microsoft's SSMS, or the sqlcmd utility

---

Some documentation regarding the image I have used can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/).

More information on the command I have used [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest).